# How to get error description in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have the following code to get some data via `.ajax call. When`.ajax`executes it redirects to an`error` handler.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#ctl00_ContentMain_ddlRegions').change(function(){
        region = $(this).val();
        alert(region);              
    });         
        $('input[type="text"]').autocomplete({ 
          source: function(request, response)
          {
            $.ajax({
                url: "EmailActivation/EmailActivation.asmx/GetIsoFromRegion",
                data: "{ 'region': '" + region + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(response){
                    alert("error: fails");
                }, 
                failure: function(response){
                    alert("failure: fails");
                }                      
            });
          },
          select: function(e,i){
            $("#<%=hfIso.ClientID %>").val("retrieved"); 
          },
          minLength: 4  
        });  
});
```

How can I find out what error I'm getting, so I can fix whatever happens?

Thank you

Comment: You have it already in argument : error: function(response)<br>
Response is the error object, you can play with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't valid json. As a rule of thumb, never build json strings via concatenation, use a library instead:

```
var data = { "region" : region };
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

As for how you can find the error, you can start by looking at your network tab. I assume it's a 500 error from the server, which can be found through logging or debugging.

Comment: Also, in the jQuery AJAX call, the `data` property can just be an object: `data: data`. No need to stringify.

Comment: Found the error by: `$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, opt){
                     alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
     });` Got url wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: I added the following code:

```
   $(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, opt){
      alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    });
```

Thank you for your input guys.